# How to clone required folder from `git` repository?

Tags: git

here is my path to images folder in `git`. I don't what anything other then `images` folder from here..

Just I would like to clone the `images` alone using `cmd` command line. how to do that?

I tried like this: (i decide to copy in to images folder)

```
D:\Tutorials\Angular\projects\Pro\slideShow>git clone https://github.com/simpult
on/angular-photo-slider/tree/master/images images
Cloning into 'images'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/simpulton/angular-photo-slider/tree/master
/images/' not found 

D:\Tutorials\Angular\projects\Pro\slideShow>
```

I didn't get any result. is it possible with git? any one guide me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot clone a specific folder from a git repository you will need to clone the whole thing and delete what you do not want.

use the regular git command but add the folder name at the end to add the git folder to a specific directory

```
git clone github.com/simpulton/angular-photo-slider.git folder-name
```

Comment: the folder name is, which folder i required is? - right

Comment: No, I am not get any result still. here is my try: `
D:\Tutorials\Angular\projects\Pro\slideShow>git clone https://github.com/simpult
on/angular-photo-slider/tree/master images
Cloning into 'images'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/simpulton/angular-photo-slider/tree/master
/' not found

D:\Tutorials\Angular\projects\Pro\slideShow>
`

Comment: are you sure your using the right repository url? because it does not seem like it

Comment: even you could try the same. the repository is exist. here is the link: https://github.com/simpulton/angular-photo-slider/tree/master/

Comment: I guess something wrong here. still no luck. here is my try:
`
D:\Tutorials\Angular\projects\Pro\slideShow>git clone https://github.com/simpulton/angular-photo-slider.git images
fatal: destination path 'images' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Comment: you already have an images directory in that folder. delete it or change the desired folder name or move to another folder